# Ajax code the auto refresh a php file and updates it's vaules

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

First I want admit that I have no knowledge in ajax. I'm building a small application, where I have a load.php file and within it, I have echoed 3 variables, i.e `$loadout[0];` `$loadout[1]; $loadout[2];`
The PHP file is working fine and showing up the values.
Now I have another html page index.html which will actually users see. In this html file have 3 divs on the body

```
<div id="out1"></div>
<div id="out2"></div>
<div id="out3"></div>
```

Now I want you people to help me with the ajax code, which will keep reloading the load.php file of mine and keep updating the output values on the respective div. But index.html page will not reload. load.php will reload inside hiddenly in every 1 sec.

Please help. What will be the ajax code?

Comment: Unless you edit the question to demonstrate trying something - you're asking [the wrong type of question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: shall we be scrolling the page for you too ?

Comment: @iSaumya Please try your self with ajax code and if you are getting any issues that ask here..no one will help you to write the ajax code here.

Comment: What wrong I have done? Please tell me. I just share my problem.

Comment: You should learn some ajax instead of asking each time a question and blindly copipasting the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your load.php at the end:

```
echo json_encode($loadout);
```

In index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//Calling function
repeatAjax();


function repeatAjax(){
jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'load.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(resp) {
                    jQuery('#out1').html(resp[0]);
                    jQuery('#out2').html(resp[1]);
                    jQuery('#out3').html(resp[2]);

          },
          complete: function() {
                setTimeout(repeatAjax,1000); //After completion of request, time to redo it after a second
             }
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: +1 , for the answer !

Comment: Hi, I just did it in a little other way. Everything is working fine but the repeat is not happening after 1 second. This is my code:

`  $.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : "load.php",
   dataType : "html",
   data : $(this).serialize(),
   success : function(response) {
    var b = response;
    var temp = new Array();
    temp = b.split(' ');
    $("#toper").html(temp[0]);
    $("#top").html(temp[1]);
    $("#stage").html(temp[2]);
   },
   complete: function() {
                setTimeout(repeatAjax,1000); //After completion of request, time to redo it after a second
             }
  })`

Comment: repeatAjax is a function name, put your whole ajax function into another function (just like above) and write that function's name in setTimeout(). Also I think dataType should be 'json' and not 'html'

Comment: Thank you thank you you thankyou thank you. I havedone it. Love you <3 Thanks....

Comment: And you don't need to split the response object like you did above because already the php is passing it as an array, just use it like response[0], response[1] etc.